# SQL Server 2008 conditional select to output multiple true values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Table:

```
Date = 20120101, ID = 123456, ParentID = 654321, System1 = 1, System2 = 1
```

User can be active in `System1`, `System2`, or both (1 = true, 0 = false). Query needs to output as follows:

```
System1   System2
1         0            "System1", "All"
0         1            "System2", "All"
1         1            "System1", "System2", "All"
0         0            "All"
```

I was trying a case statement but I couldn't get it to output how I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm getting the idea that you want to generate multiple rows for each row in your data.

If so, the following does this:

```
select a.*
from ((select t.*, 'ALL' as thecode
       from t
      ) union all
      (select t.*, 'System1'
       from t
       where system1 = 1
      ) union all
      (select t.*, 'System2'
       from t
       where system2 = 1
      )
     ) a
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon this is perfect!

Answer (score 2):

```
select *,
         case when system1 = 1 and system2 = 0 then 'System1, All'
              when system1 = 1 and system2 = 1 then 'System1, System2, All'
              when system1 = 0 and system2 = 0 then 'All'
              when system1 = 0 and system2 = 1 then 'System2, All'
         end as output
from your_table
```